# Directive is buggy bootstrap nav - angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

here is my code - it works however if someone clicks outside of the target area (the text label) the directive does not fire.

Directive:

```
//bootstrap change active menu class
app.directive('activeClass', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            $(element).on('click', function() {
                $(".nav div").removeClass("activeTab");
                element.addClass("activeTab");
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Bootstrap nav bar:

```
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-show="isMentor">
            <li >
                <a href="/home" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><div active-class>Home</div></a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/myGoals" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"><div active-class>My goals</div></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I want the directive to only affect the div but fire if the  tag is clicked. How can I do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach directive to li , and than change to javascript like this:

```
app.directive('activeClass', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        $(element).on('click', function() {
            $(".nav div").removeClass("activeTab");
            element.find('div').addClass("activeTab");
        });
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Thanks that works, but what happens if I had multiple divs and I did element. find?

Comment: than you would need to add some specific class to the div you actually want and do element.find('.specific-class')

Comment: $(element).find('.specific-class') is the correct way, angular jQLite find is restrained to tags